# Get list of all pages available in a web site

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a list of all the pages of a particular site

For example, https://github.com: https://github.com/login, https://github.com/signup, https://github.com/developmedev
...

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. There is no list that has everything. All you can do is to parse the entrance page, like `https://github.com/`, find all links that go out of it, and recursively repeat

Comment: It's technically impossible because a site can keep making pages dynamically. There was a time in the 90s when some people thought having their site indexed by search engines was bad (!) so they created pages with links to more dynamically-generated URLs, and those pages did the same, and so on, just to confound search engines.